# What do nested generics in C# mean?

Tags: c#, generics, nested-generics

A bit of a basic question, but one that seems to stump me, nonetheless.

Given a "nested generic":

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

Is this stating that IEnumerable can have generic types that are themselves KeyValuePair 's ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The KeyValuePair type expects two generic type parameters. We can either populate them by pointing to concrete types:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
```

Or we can populate them by using other generic parameters already specified by the outer class:

```
class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

Generic type parameters are always specified "at-use", or at the point where you are using the class or method that requires them. And just like any other parameter, you can fill it with a constant, hard-coded value (or type in this case), or another variable.

Comment: Thanks!  As I said, always seems to stump me, but good to know I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is "An IEnumerable of Key/Value pairs."  It would be declared thusly:

```
IEnumberable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> reallyComplicatedDictionary =
    new IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

Or similar.

About the only think I can think this particular usage would do is allow you to have a "dictionary" with repeated keys.

Comment: Hmm, when did we become able to make new IEnumerables? ;)

Comment: this *is* part of the Dictionary contract. The uniqueness is just enforced implicitly rather than explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In a nut shell, it means that when you enumerate over that `IEnumerable`, you're going to get `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` (for whatever types `TKey` and `TValue` are set to).

So, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
```

The IEnumerable itself is not a generic. It knows that it is going to contain KeyValuePair. Here KeyValuePair is the generic which can contain any 2 generic types.